# Como inicializar a classe a partir de lista de listas e que possa receber listas únicas ao objeto retornando uma nova instância deste objeto?

Tags: python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos

**Objetivo**:
Inicializar a classe a partir da lista de listas do Python e armazena-la na instância variável chamada data. Também deve ter a opção de adicionar listas únicas ao objeto. Onde deve retornar uma nova instância deste objeto com um elemento adicional.
por exemplo:

```
>>> analisador = meu_analisador + ['G03-01', 789,01, 129,00, 0,00008]
>>> analizador.data

Output:
  [
    ['L01-10', 1007,67, 102,88, 1,001], ['L01-06', 996,42, 99,68, 2,00087], 
    ['G02-03', 1111,95, 125,04, 3,001], ['G03-06', 989,01, 119,0, 4,00004], 
  ]
```

Implementei esta classe e já tentei resolver a questão a cima de diversas formas, como por exemplo, utilizando *iteradores, métodos e classes especiais* etc... Mas não consegui achar uma solução para tal. Então vim pedir a ajuda de vocês nessa questão.

**MEU CÓDIGO :**

```
data =[
        ["L01-10", 1007.67, 102.88, 1.00100], ["L01-06", 996.42, 99.68, 2.00087],
        ["L02-13", 987.63, 101.88, 1.34100], ["L02-14", 981.63, 105.88, 1.04100],
        ['L01-10', 1000.02, 102.88, 1.00100], ['L01-06', 999.90, 96.00, 2.00087],
        ['G02-03', 1000, 96.50, 3.00100], ['G03-06', 989.01, 119.00, 4.00004]
      ]


class Analize:
    """ TODO: Part 1 - Adicione o(s) método(s) necessário(s) para cumprir os requisitos. """
    def __init__(self, dados: list) -> None:
        unico = []
        listas = []
    
        for i in base_data:
            if type(i) == list():
                listas.append(i)
            else:
                unico.append(i)
        self.data = listas + unico


    def verify_series(self,
                      ids: str,
                      wgt: float,
                      rate: float,
                      imp: float) -> bool:
        """ 
        TODO: Part 2 - Valida a tipagem dos parâmetros passados e
         verifica se os mesmos já está contido no self.data.
        """

        verify = [ids, wgt, rate, imp]

        # VERIFICANDO SE O ATRIBUTO series_id ESTÁ CONTIDO EM Self.data --------
        for i in self.data:
            for j in verify:
                if i != j:
                    return ValueError('{}series is not present within the dataset'.format(j))
        return True

dados = Analize(data)
a = dados.data + ['B07-03', 1000, 96.50, 3.00100]
data.verify_series(ids='L01', wgt=100, rate=0.05, imp=0.001)  # Response: True
data.verify_series(ids='B03', wgt=100, rate=0.05, imp=0.001)  # Response: Error
```

**RESPOSTA** :

```
True

ValueError: B03 series is not present within the dataset.

[['L01-10', 1007.67, 102.88, 1.001], 
 ['L01-06', 996.42, 99.68, 2.00087], 
 ['L02-13', 987.63, 101.88, 1.341], 
 ['L02-14', 981.63, 105.88, 1.041], 
 ['L01-10', 1000.02, 102.88, 1.001], 
 ['L01-06', 999.9, 96.0, 2.00087], 
 ['G02-03', 1000, 96.5, 3.001], 
  'B07-03', 1000, 96.5, 3.001]
```

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade a solução é bem simples.

Você pode utilizar o metodo mágico `__add__` para resolver esse seu problema, para saber mais sobre esse método sugiro consultar este site [aqui](https://blog.finxter.com/python-__add__/). Este método permite que você crie uma nova instancia de sua classe adicionando novos parametros, além de resolver o erro com o operador `+`.

A resolução ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```py
class Analyzer:
    data = []

    def __init__(self, data: list):
        self.data = data

    def __add__(self, other):
            self.data.append(other)
            return Analyzer(self.data) # retorna nova instancia com a modificação do data

    (...)
```